# Check whether Apache loaded a specific config?

Tags: apache-2.2

Having many configuration files,
I put up one file but I don't see its effects.

Either my config is WRONG, OR the config files are NOT LOADED by Apache.

Is there a command I can fire to see wether a specific config file got loaded by Apache or not?

```
apachectl configtest
```

Does not print errors. Server restarts without error.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From command line you can also run the following arguments with the Apache binary to get additional information:

```
-t -D DUMP_VHOSTS  : show parsed vhost settings
-t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG : show parsed run settings
-t -D DUMP_MODULES : show all loaded modules
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

If you have the [mod_info](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_info.html) module activated, simply access

```
http://[you server's IP]/server-info
```

There you'll see the entire Apache configuration.

Comment: I have `info_module` and the address results in a 404. I think your solution generally works but not in my case..

Comment: @DanFromGermany make sure that you also have appropriate handlers configured as per that link. If you get 404 that means Apache is not treating it as `mod_info` request but rather a regular one.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with apachectl.

`apachectl -D DUMP_INCLUDES`

or

`apachectl -D DUMP_INCLUDES -f /path/to/your/httpd.conf`